# Using getchar() on c gets the 'Enter' after input

Tags: c, getchar

I'm trying to write a simple program that asks a user to choose from a menu in a loop.
I use getchar() to get the input, however i've noticed that when I enter a char and press 'Enter' the program makes two loops (as if i pressed twice) one the char as an input and another for 'Enter' as an input.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

`getchar()` returns the first character in the input buffer, and removes it from the input buffer. But other characters are still in the input buffer (`\n` in your example). You need to clear the input buffer before calling `getchar()` again:

```
void clearInputBuffer() // works only if the input buffer is not empty
{
    do 
    {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to filter out the enter key as the return value from `getchar`

```
char c = (char)getchar();
if ( c != '\n' ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant getchar()? if so getchar() returns int.

Comment: @Nyan, `getchar` does indeed return `int` but it's legal to assign to `char` via conversions.  Reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/

Comment: @Jared: yes, but char is limited to (tipically) 256 values, and you need (tipically) 257 values to identify **ALL** characters **AND** EOF. That's why `getchar()` returns an int

Comment: @pmg, I'm aware of that.  I'm merely demonstrating what the OP asked for (how to check for newline).

Comment: Ok, but you can demonstrate with `int c` too :-)

Comment: I declared it as int as linux man states for getchar() return value.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `getchar()` after the `getchar()` :P

Comment: I guess It would work, but its quiet anaesthetic.

Comment: That will produce problems in some cases where the user will find themselves having to press return twice.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*! getline() reads one line from standard input and copies it to line array
 * (but no more than max chars).
 * It does not place the terminating \n in line array.
 * Returns line length, or 0 for empty line, or EOF for end-of-file.
 */
int getline(char line[], int max)
{
  int nch = 0;
  int c;
  max = max - 1;            /* leave room for '\0' */

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n')
      break;

    if (nch < max) {
      line[nch] = c;
      nch = nch + 1;
    }
  }

  if (c == EOF && nch == 0)
    return EOF;

  line[nch] = '\0';
  return nch;
}
```

[Source](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~efif/courses/Software1_Spring_04/practices/practice3.php)

Comment: I must not use string or char arrays(its a work for a course)

Answer (score 1):

You've kind of answered your own question; you have to deal with the newline character somehow.

There are several options.  If your menu options are *numbered*, you can use `scanf()` to read in an integer value and switch based on that:

```
printf("Pick an option: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &option);
switch(option)
{
  case 0 : do_something(); break;
  case 1 : do_something_else(); break;
  ...
  default: bad_option(); break;
}
```

The advantage of this option is that the `%d` conversion specifier skips over any leading whitespace, including newline characters, so you don't have to worry about any unread `\n` clogging up the input stream (in fact, most of the conversion specifiers skip leading whitespace; `%c` doesn't, making it behave a lot like `getchar()`).

The disadvantage of this option is that if someone fat-fingers a non-digit character in their input, it won't be read with the `%d` conversion specifier, and will stay stuck in the input stream until a call to `getchar()` or `scanf()` with a `%s` or `%c` conversion specifier.

A better option is to read all input as character *strings* using `fgets()`, then parse and validate as necessary.

```
/**
 * Prints a prompt to stdout and reads an input response, writing
 * the input value to option.  
 *
 * @param prompt [in]  - prompt written to stdout
 * @param option [out] - option entered by user
 *
 * @return - 1 on success, 0 on failure.  If return value is 0, then option
 * is not changed.
 */
int getOption(const char *prompt, char *option)
{
  char input[3]; // option char + newline + 0 terminator
  int result = 0;

  printf("%s: ", prompt);  
  fflush(stdout);

  if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
  {
    /**
     * Search for a newline character in the input buffer; if it's not
     * present, then the user entered more characters than the input buffer 
     * can store.  Reject the input, and continue to read from stdin until
     * we see a newline character; that way we don't leave junk in the
     * input stream to mess up a future read.
     */
    char *newline = strchr(input, '\n');
    if (!newline)
    {
      printf("Input string is too long and will be rejected\n");
      /**
       * Continue reading from stdin until we find the newline
       * character
       */
      while (!newline && fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
        newline = strchr(input, '\n');
    }
    else
    {
      *option = input[0];
      result = 1;
    }
  }
  else
    printf("Received error or EOF on read\n");

  return result;
}
```

Yes, that's a lot of work to read in one stupid menu option, and that's the simple version.  Welcome to the wonderful world of interactive input processing in C.