# C++ do...whille loop duplicate prints with getchar function

Tags: c++, loops, duplicates, do-while, getchar

The code below is printing "Menu" twice when input is different from 3.

```
do{
    puts("Menu");
    option = getchar();
}
while (option != '3');
```

Comment: Because of the trailing new line character maybe?

Comment: It will print "Menu" every time it goes around that loop. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @GrahamS forgiveness, friend. Maybe I was not very clear. But when the code is small so I think it's valid test it. The method "getchar" expects a key, but it comes after the puts ("menu"), then "menu" has already been printed once, but if I press 3 and "enter", even on the first run of the line "option = getchar ()", "menu" is printed again, but should not, should just test the" while "and exit the loop.

Comment: @Rafael: no problem. It wasn't clear from the question what you thought the issue was. What you are really asking is: "Why does it go round the loop twice when you enter a character that is not '3' ?"
You could find the answer by looking at the value of `option` in your debugger on each iteration of the loop. If you don't have a debugger then you could add a `putchar(option)`.
As others have answered, when you enter something `getchar` will get the character on the first iteration and then the newline character on the second.

Comment: @GrahamS I have no debugger. So thank you for the tip of the use of "putchar ()".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix:

`do{
    puts("Menu");
    std::cin >> option;
}
while (option != '3');`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to flush your stdin. When your program reaches getChar, it finds the newline character, and processes it as an input character.

if your not set on using `getChar()` to retrieve the input a better option would probably be to use `std::cin`, as it deals with white space such as this more intelligently

You can also flush the input by adding the line `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` right before you retrieve the character from the input.

or you can run an if statement to check if the character retrieved is newline

```
if ( option != '\n' ) {
 ...
}
```

also see this answer [Using getchar() on c gets the 'Enter' after input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969871/using-getchar-on-c-gets-the-enter-after-input)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to my learning. With IF works too.